# Add '...' to template field

Tags: templating, filter

I'm using the following code in my template to truncate the body of an entry (coming from a Rich Text field):

`{{ entry.body | slice(0, 500) | markdown }}`

To this, I'd like to add `...` as a string, so that it will output like:

`Words words words...`

Since the field part I'm using outputs into its own `<p>` tag, adding the `...` into the HTML itself has them sitting in two different tags. I've tried using `|join` but I must be doing something wrong, its putting the first part into a separate `<p>` tag than the `...`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
{{ (entry.body | slice(0, 500) ~ '...') | markdown }}
```

Comment: This is probably really close, but it's not converting it to markdown. Is there a smarter way of outputting the Rich Text's content?

Comment: This works perfectly: `{{ (entry.body | slice(0, 500) ~ '...') | markdown }}`

Answer (score 3):

You might find the Hacksaw plugin useful for this https://github.com/ehousestudio/craft_hacksaw/ this will truncate text for you and has a wealth of options available for doing so, specifically the `append` parameter, which will do exactly what you want :)

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'd rather not use a plugin, but this will be my back up answer :)